# How to streamimg hololens 2 video to PC UWP app?

Tags: uwp, video-streaming, hololens

I already have a UWP app run on the hololens2,and it will do something like show preview camera photo.

Today I want to streaming the preview photo to my PC UWP app
I had try the Device portal API but it will delay 2~3 seconds.

I also tried the MixedReality-WebRTC and Windows-universal-samples-Windows-universal-samples,but they all need cpature devices and my pc without any capture devices.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Please forgive me for being terrible in my English.

I had try to initialize PeerConnection,but I get an error like this:
[Unhandled exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIsSx.png)

Answer (score 0):

To share the first-person perspective as a video stream for the local user, you can also leverage built-in Miracast support to stream videos to the display receivers(such as your PC). For more information, please refer to Mixed Reality official doc:[Shared experiences in mixed reality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/shared-experiences-in-mixed-reality#share-first-person-perspective).

Besides, video capture is optional for two peers in the MixedReality-WebRTC -- local media track (sender) and one remote media track (receiver), both of which can be null.  So, if don’t have any capture devices, you don't have to add source local/remote media in your app.

Comment: Thank for your answer!
I just wnat to get my hololens camera video so I will not use Shared experiences in mixed reality.

And I am tried to don`t add MediaCapture in my app.
But when I initialize PeerConnection I will get an error "Unhandled exception: A serious program has been requested to end."

I had edited my question.

Comment: Could you try cloning the UWP C# sample app project [MixedReality-WebRTC-TestAppUwp](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/tree/release/1.0/examples/TestAppUwp) as your PC side receiver? This sample demonstrates audio/video/data communication by means of a simple video chat app.

Comment: Unfortunately,I I still get the same error.

Comment: And I trid the tutorial on my another notebook.
This time I can find my capture device,but when run to init peerConnection I get same error again.